# benchmarking application

Tags: performance, benchmarking

I would like to measure a performance of a particular application say M.S word in particular period of time.
so, is there any application or toolkit that help me to read and report the processor and the memory performance for just a specific application not the whole system?

Comment: #define performance please. What you are describing is merely the process' resource usage, which may have nothing to do with what its user perceives as "performance"...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Sysinternals utilities? Process Monitor might be what you're looking for.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545021